# how to run recursive function in Java

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to learn Dynamic Programming and one of the examples they give in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) of what is not Dynamic Programming, is a recursive way of getting Fibonacci sequence up to certain number. I.E.

Given a recursive function, say:

```
fib(n) = 0 if n = 0
         1 if n = 1
         fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) if n >= 2
```

We can easily write this recursively from its mathematic form as:

```
function fib(n)
  if(n == 0 || n == 1)
    n
  else
    fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

But I cannot get the pseudo code to work.

when I do this method in Java, I get an error *the operator + is undefined for methods void*:

```
 public void fib(int n) {

     if (n == 0 || n == 1) {

         System.out.println(n);
     } else
         return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);

 }
```

Comment: Your sudo code suggests System.out.println(n); should actually be return n

Comment: @RossDrew I use the upgraded sudo code, it's guaranteed to give the correct-answer(TM)

Comment: @RichardTingle Sudo code, now that is boss

Comment: @RichardTingle well it's guaranteed to give AN answer

Comment: @RossDrew This program operates as coded; could there be any better definition of correct?

Comment: @RichardTingle mofo it was missing the returns and and int declarations, ok ? so it does not work by definition

Comment: @RossDrew "guaranteed"  ;-);-)

Comment: what you talking about? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in the line with `return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)`, you add the return values of the fib() function. So you should actually return a (int) value, even if n==0||n==1.

```
 public int fib(int n) {

     if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
         return n;
     }
     else {
         return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
     }
 }
```

you then call and print you result from **outside** the function:

```
System.out.println(fib(42));
```

Answer (score 4):

It has no return type so you can't mathematically add it to anything, let alone itself.

```
public void fib(int n)  //returning void
```

Give it a return type

```
public int fib(int n) //yey \o/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public class Test
{
public static int fib( int n )
{
    if ( n == 0 || n == 1 )
        return n;
    else
        return fib( n - 1 ) + fib( n - 2 );
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    System.out.println(fib( 6 ));
}
}
```

Comment: there is nothing to explain in this. The code snippet by Eduardo Dennis clearly depicts that the method do not return anything but still in else statement this method is called using return and + operator. Definitely will get a compilation error.

Comment: ^ that was an explanation :P

Answer (score 1):

Just  change return type of fib function to int. 
and in function change

```
if (n == 0 || n == 1){return n; }
```